# Error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined

Tags: string, arguments, undefined

---

- 

---

---

### Matching User while logging in

```
     const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
     const mongoose = require('mongoose');
     const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

     // Load User Model
     const User = require('../models/User');

     module.exports = function(passport) {
     passport.use(
      new LocalStrategy({ username: 'username' }, (username,  
          password, done) => {

        // Match User
        User.findOne({ username: username })
            .then(user => {
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'username is 
                    not registered' });
                }

                // Match Password
                bcrypt.compare(password, user.hashedPassword, (err, 
                       isMatch) => {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    if (isMatch) {
                        return done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        return done(null, false, { message: 
                        'Password incorrect' });
                    }
                });
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err))
    })
);

     passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
         done(null, user.id);
     });

     passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
         User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
            done(err, user);
         });
     });
    }
```

---

### Validation pass while registering user

```
    User.findOne({ username: username })
        .then(async user => {
            if (user) {
                //User exists
                errors.push({ msg: "username has already taken" });
                res.render('register', {
                    errors,
                    username,
                    password
                });
            } else {

                const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
                const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password,               

                salt);


                const newUser = new User({
                    username: username,
                    password: hashedPassword,
                });
                newUser.save()
                    .then(user => {
                        // res.status(201).json(user);
                        req.flash('success_msg', 'You are now  
                        registered')
                        res.redirect('/users/login');
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));

            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
}
```

---

### ../models/User

```
    // Importing modules
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


       const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
           username: {
               type: String,
               lowercase: true,
               unique: true,
               // required: [true, "can't be blank"],
               match: [/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, 'is invalid'],
               index: true
          },
          password: {
               type: String,
               required: true
          },
          Date: {
               type: Date,
               default: Date.now
          }

          }, { timestamps: true });


      // export userschema
         module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

why is it showing the error "Error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined". The same error was throwing when saving the password as hash in DB and now the same error throwing while comparing the hashed password. I checked the documentation, the format is the same but I think there is a syntactical error.

Comment: What language is that code in?

Comment: this is node js

Comment: you do not say in which line you get the error. But I only see one possible line - the first. What's `user.hashedPassword`? Is it possible that this property is actually `undefined`?

Comment: @JohannesH., yes you are right actually I'm new at posting questions so I forgot to mention the line of error. I'm getting the error exact there, I tried after removing "user." but then it says hashedPassword is not define

Comment: Well, nobody can tell you where and how your hashed password is defined, as we don't know the code that defines it...

Comment: @JohannesH. I did some changes, kindly let me know if this helps, Thanks.

Comment: Please show `../models/User`

Comment: @JohannesH. please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the definition of the User data type, only the fields `username` and `password` exist. There is no field `hashedPassword`. However, you're trying to access this field in the line saying `bcrypt.compare(password, user.hashedPassword ...`.

You're stroring the hased password in the `password` field here:

```
const newUser = new User({
                    username: username,
                    password: hashedPassword,
                });
```

So later, you also need to read it from the password field:

`bcrypt.compare(password, user.password ...`